# How can Upload the Docx, Doc file on Cloud Server Storage

Tags: oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure-classic

I have uploaded as per Oracle Documentation but didn't get in same format. [here is postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mGZP.png) next when get request for same file is here after getting from server.[my docx file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSKj2.png)
please let me know what i missed. thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you are asking and I will post a detailed response.  Do you absolutely need to use postman?  There exists a Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Object Storage Classic File Transfer Manager command-line tool which is much easier ( once it's configured )

Answer (score 0):

You used POST in your postman call, instead of PUT.
POST in this case is used as the command for creating or updating the **metadata**, not the **object**.

Try it with PUT instead.

[See the Oracle Cloud Storage documentation for this as well](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/iaas/storage-cloud/ssapi/op-v1-%7Baccount%7D-%7Bcontainer%7D-%7Bobject%7D-put.html#examples).